# how to stop while looping for bash

Tags: bash, for

```
target=${1:-http://web1.com}
while true 
do
    for i in $(seq 10)
    do
    curl $target > /dev/null & 
done

    wait

done
```

I am just a beginner at writing in programming especially bash.
I want to train my HTTP load balancing by giving 10 HTTP requests at one time. and stop sending the request when it reaches 15000.

how can I write the code? thank you

Comment: At the moment you're running the inner loop inside an infinite outer loop. Making the outer loop run 1500 times make the script do 15000 requests in total. If this is not what you meant, then please clarify the question.

Comment: yes, so the loop will run 1500 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to achieve is to call `curl` a total of 15000 times, then what you need to do is to run your outer loop 1500 times.

You could do that by simply running the outer loop 1500 times in a similar way that you run the inner loop ten times:

```bsh
target=${1:-http://web1.com}
j=0

while [ "$j" -lt 1500 ]; do

    for i in {0..9}; do
        curl "$target" >/dev/null &
    done

    wait

    j=$(( j + 1 ))
done
```

Or you could count the total number of times you call `curl`, which would allow you to change the number of times you run `curl` in the inner loop without having to adjust the outer loop at all and still retain the same number of total calls:

```bsh
target=${1:-http://web1.com}
n=15000

while [ "$n" -gt 0 ]; do

    for i in {0..9}; do
        curl "$target" >/dev/null &
        n=$(( n - 1 ))
    done

    wait

done
```

The test `[ "$n" -gt 0 ]` is *true* for as long as `n` is strict greater than zero.

Or, to avoid decreasing `n` inside the inner loop:

```bsh
target=${1:-http://web1.com}
n=15000

while [ "$n" -gt 0 ]; do

    for i in {0..9}; do
        curl "$target" >/dev/null &
    done
    n=$(( n - 10 ))

    wait

done
```

Or, you have a `xargs` utility that can run things in parallel with `-P`, and you want to keep 10 `curl` processes running constantly:

```bsh
target=${1:-http://web1.com}
n=15000

yes | head -n "$n" | xargs -I {} -P 10 curl "$target" >/dev/null
```

This creates 15000 lines using `yes` and `head` and feeds them into a `xargs` command that will keep 10 `curl` processes running at any time until all lines have been exhausted (one `curl` process will be spawned for each line read from `head`).  The actual contents of the lines generated by `yes` will be the single character `y`, but these are thrown away and not used at all.

Comment: man thanks a lot, I am gonna update it soon. I have tried all the code and the latest one is simple and suits my scenario. I am gonna give an update after I finished and give the conclution.